# Camera Rotation Issue in Unity3D C# (likely easy fix)

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, camera, rotation

I have got some CS code here which I am attempting to use in unity to rotate a camera around the y axis. The issue is that the camera currently seems to rotate around the z axis, which is causing some visual difficulties in my game.

```
public class TouchCamera : MonoBehaviour {
Vector2?[] oldTouchPositions = {
    null,
    null
};
Vector2 oldTouchVector;
float oldTouchDistance;

void Update() {
    if (Input.touchCount == 0) {
        oldTouchPositions[0] = null;
        oldTouchPositions[1] = null;
    }
    else if (Input.touchCount == 1) {
        if (oldTouchPositions[0] == null || oldTouchPositions[1] != null) {
            oldTouchPositions[0] = Input.GetTouch(0).position;
            oldTouchPositions[1] = null;
        }
        else {
            Vector2 newTouchPosition = Input.GetTouch(0).position;

            transform.position += transform.TransformDirection((Vector3)((oldTouchPositions[0] - newTouchPosition) * GetComponent<Camera>().orthographicSize / GetComponent<Camera>().pixelHeight * 2f));

            oldTouchPositions[0] = newTouchPosition;
        }
    }
    else {
        if (oldTouchPositions[1] == null) {
            oldTouchPositions[0] = Input.GetTouch(0).position;
            oldTouchPositions[1] = Input.GetTouch(1).position;
            oldTouchVector = (Vector2)(oldTouchPositions[0] - oldTouchPositions[1]);
            oldTouchDistance = oldTouchVector.magnitude;
        }
        else {
            Vector2 screen = new Vector2(GetComponent<Camera>().pixelWidth, GetComponent<Camera>().pixelHeight);

            Vector2[] newTouchPositions = {
                Input.GetTouch(0).position,
                Input.GetTouch(1).position
            };
            Vector2 newTouchVector = newTouchPositions[0] - newTouchPositions[1];
            float newTouchDistance = newTouchVector.magnitude;

            transform.position += transform.TransformDirection((Vector3)((oldTouchPositions[0] + oldTouchPositions[1] - screen) * GetComponent<Camera>().orthographicSize / screen.y));
            transform.localRotation *= Quaternion.Euler(new Vector3(0, 0, Mathf.Asin(Mathf.Clamp((oldTouchVector.y * newTouchVector.x - oldTouchVector.x * newTouchVector.y) / oldTouchDistance / newTouchDistance, -1f, 1f)) / 0.0174532924f));
            GetComponent<Camera>().orthographicSize *= oldTouchDistance / newTouchDistance;
            transform.position -= transform.TransformDirection((newTouchPositions[0] + newTouchPositions[1] - screen) * GetComponent<Camera>().orthographicSize / screen.y);

            oldTouchPositions[0] = newTouchPositions[0];
            oldTouchPositions[1] = newTouchPositions[1];
            oldTouchVector = newTouchVector;
            oldTouchDistance = newTouchDistance;
        }
    }
}
```

I am and artist and by no means a coder and this code is not my creation. I am just seeking assistance in correcting it to suit my needs. So if someone can let me know the most simplistic adjustment I can make to this current code I would much appreciate it. I know this is not the most conventional question, I am just hoping for a little help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right–this is a really easy fix. All you need to do to change the axis of rotation is tweak the the following line (roughly line 49):

```
transform.localRotation *= Quaternion.Euler(new Vector3(0, 0, Mathf.Asin(Mathf.Clamp((oldTouchVector.y * newTouchVector.x - oldTouchVector.x * newTouchVector.y) / oldTouchDistance / newTouchDistance, -1f, 1f)) / 0.0174532924f));
```

You'll notice the part that starts

```
new Vector3
```

Which has three arguments,

```
new Vector3(x value, y value, z value)
```

Right now, the Vector3 is set to

```
new Vector3(x value = 0, y value = 0, z value = rotation data)
```

To rotate the camera around its y axis, swap the line for this

```
transform.localRotation *= Quaternion.Euler(new Vector3(0, Mathf.Asin(Mathf.Clamp((oldTouchVector.y * newTouchVector.x - oldTouchVector.x * newTouchVector.y) / oldTouchDistance / newTouchDistance, -1f, 1f)) / 0.0174532924f, 0));
```

All I did was swap the current settings for the y and z values in the new Vector3. Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks! Although there is one issue which I am now seeing from testing. After a rotation is initiated the other swipe functions no longer work. So if I swipe to the side then rotate, I can no longer swipe. It seems strange and I am hoping this is a quick fix. Also, is there any way to have it rotate inwards? Atm it rotates with the camera facing outwards. Thanks :)

Comment: Seems as though the swiping works after a reboot and second test, so perhaps it was just a strange bug. However, I would still like any info anyone may have with regards to have the camera rotate facing inwards!

Comment: So what I think you're after is to get the camera to rotate around a point outside of the camera, rather than around one of the camera's local axes. This is a much harder task to accomplish, as you must first specify a reference point in worldspace around which the camera should rotate. This might be fixed, for instance, 20 units in front of the camera, or you might want to select a custom point/object to rotate around. Without knowing what you're after, I can't really help much. Sorry about that.

Comment: Yes, I would like the camera to orbit a space in front of it. No particular game object but simply a certain distance away which would make the rotation seem natural. At the moment it rotate facing outwards. I believe I am just after the opposite of that however in order to do so I do realize it would need to be orbiting a space which is in front of it.

Comment: I'll try to get back to you if I can, as I don't have time to write up a solution right now. However, I recommend talking with your programmer, as he or she will have a better idea of what you're after.

Comment: See my new answer for instructions on making your Camera focus on and orbit around a point in space.

Answer (score 0):

See my previous answer's comment thread for context on this answer.

There are two approaches to get your camera to orbit around a point. Before you do anything else, create an empty GameObject in Unity and set it at the fixed point around which you wish your camera to orbit. Make sure the GameObject is in the Camera's line of sight. Then parent your camera to the Empty GameObject.

For the easy (but more rigid) approach, attach your TouchCamera script to the Empty GameObject. Remove the TouchCamera script from your camera. Now add this line `public Camera camera` above the start of the Update method in the script. In your script replace all occurrences of `GetComponent<Camera>()` with `camera`. Save your script and go back into Unity. Finally, click on your Empty GameObject and drag your Camera into the Serialized Camera field in your TouchCamera component. This approach essentially moves control of the camera to the Empty GameObject.

For a more convoluted (but more flexible) approach, create a new C# script and name it "CameraControl". Then copy and paste the following code into the script (replacing any code already there).

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System;
using System.Collections;

public class CameraControl : MonoBehaviour {

Vector2?[] oldTouchPositions = {
    null,
    null
};
Vector2 oldTouchVector;
float oldTouchDistance;

public Transform CenterOfRotation;
public Camera camera;

private Vector2 actualCenter;
private Vector2 prevTouchDelta;
private Vector3 prevMousePosition;
private bool rotate;

void Start()
{
    //swap with below commented line for y rotation.
    actualCenter = new Vector2(CenterOfRotation.position.x, CenterOfRotation.position.z);
    //actualCenter = new Vector2(CenterOfRotation.position.x, CenterOfRotation.position.y);
}

void Update() {
    if(!rotate){

        if (Input.touchCount == 0) {
            oldTouchPositions[0] = null;
            oldTouchPositions[1] = null;
        }
        else if (Input.touchCount == 1) {
            if (oldTouchPositions[0] == null || oldTouchPositions[1] != null) {
                oldTouchPositions[0] = Input.GetTouch(0).position;
                oldTouchPositions[1] = null;
            }
            else {
                Vector2 newTouchPosition = Input.GetTouch(0).position;

                transform.position += transform.TransformDirection((Vector3)((oldTouchPositions[0] - newTouchPosition) * camera.orthographicSize / camera.pixelHeight * 2f));

                oldTouchPositions[0] = newTouchPosition;
            }
        }
        else {
            if (oldTouchPositions[1] == null) {
                oldTouchPositions[0] = Input.GetTouch(0).position;
                oldTouchPositions[1] = Input.GetTouch(1).position;
                oldTouchVector = (Vector2)(oldTouchPositions[0] - oldTouchPositions[1]);
                oldTouchDistance = oldTouchVector.magnitude;
            }
            else {
                Vector2 screen = new Vector2(camera.pixelWidth, camera.pixelHeight);

                Vector2[] newTouchPositions = {
                    Input.GetTouch(0).position,
                    Input.GetTouch(1).position
                };
                Vector2 newTouchVector = newTouchPositions[0] - newTouchPositions[1];
                float newTouchDistance = newTouchVector.magnitude;


                transform.position += transform.TransformDirection((Vector3)((oldTouchPositions[0] + oldTouchPositions[1] - screen) * camera.orthographicSize / screen.y));
                //transform.localRotation *= Quaternion.Euler(new Vector3(0, Mathf.Asin(Mathf.Clamp((oldTouchVector.y * newTouchVector.x - oldTouchVector.x * newTouchVector.y) / oldTouchDistance / newTouchDistance, -1f, 1f)) / 0.0174532924f, 0));
                camera.orthographicSize *= oldTouchDistance / newTouchDistance;
                transform.position -= transform.TransformDirection((newTouchPositions[0] + newTouchPositions[1] - screen) * camera.orthographicSize / screen.y);

                oldTouchPositions[0] = newTouchPositions[0];
                oldTouchPositions[1] = newTouchPositions[1];
                oldTouchVector = newTouchVector;
                oldTouchDistance = newTouchDistance;
            }
        }
    }
    else{
        InwardRotation();
    }

}

void OnGUI()
{
    rotate = GUILayout.Toggle(rotate, "Toggle For Rotation", "Button");
}

void InwardRotation()
{
    //mouse version
    if(Input.GetMouseButton(0))
    {
        //distance from center of screen to touch
        Vector3 centerScreen = camera.ViewportToScreenPoint(new Vector3(0.5f, 0.5f, 1));
        Vector3 mouseDelta = Input.mousePosition - new Vector3(centerScreen.x, centerScreen.y, 0f);

        //if mouse doesn't move very much, don't rotate
        if(mouseDelta.sqrMagnitude < 0.1f)
            return;

        //attempts to make movement smoother
        if(prevMousePosition == Vector3.zero)
            prevMousePosition = mouseDelta;

        //this gets the angle between the current touch and the last touch
        float theta = Mathf.Atan2(mouseDelta.y, mouseDelta.x) - Mathf.Atan2(prevMousePosition.y, prevMousePosition.x);

        //Gets the rotated coordinates of the camera. Swap with below commented line for y rotation.
        Vector2 newPos = RotatedCoordinates(transform.position.x, transform.position.z, theta, CenterOfRotation.position, true);
        //Vector2 newPos = RotatedCoordinates(transform.position.x, transform.position.y, theta, CenterOfRotation.position, true);
        Debug.Log("New Pos = " + newPos);

        //swap with below commented line for y rotation.
        transform.localPosition = new Vector3(newPos.x, transform.localPosition.y, newPos.y);
        //transform.localPosition = new Vector3(newPos.x, newPos.y, transform.localPosition.z);

        transform.LookAt(CenterOfRotation);

        prevMousePosition = mouseDelta;
    }
    if(Input.touches.Length > 0f)
    {
        //distance from center of screen to touch
        Vector3 centerScreen = camera.ViewportToScreenPoint(new Vector3(0.5f, 0.5f, 1));
        Vector2 touchDelta = Input.GetTouch(0).position - new Vector2(centerScreen.x, centerScreen.y);

        //if mouse doesn't move very much, don't rotate
        if(touchDelta.sqrMagnitude < 0.1f)
            return;

        //attempts to make movement smoother
        if(prevTouchDelta == Vector2.zero)
            prevTouchDelta = touchDelta;

        //this gets the angle between the current touch and the last touch
        float theta = Mathf.Atan2(touchDelta.y, touchDelta.x) - Mathf.Atan2(prevTouchDelta.y, prevTouchDelta.x);

        //Gets the rotated coordinates of the camera. Swap with below commented line for y rotation.
        Vector2 newPos = RotatedCoordinates(transform.position.x, transform.position.z, theta, CenterOfRotation.position, true);
        //Vector2 newPos = RotatedCoordinates(transform.position.x, transform.position.y, theta, CenterOfRotation.position, true);
        Debug.Log("New Pos = " + newPos);

        //swap with below commented line for y rotation.
        transform.localPosition = new Vector3(newPos.x, transform.localPosition.y, newPos.y);
        //transform.localPosition = new Vector3(newPos.x, newPos.y, transform.localPosition.z);

        transform.LookAt(CenterOfRotation);

        prevTouchDelta = touchDelta;
    }

    else{
        prevTouchDelta = Vector2.zero;
    }
}

/// <summary>
/// This method returns the coordinates of a plane rotated about its origin. It translates a point from one place on a unit circle to another. 
/// </summary>
/// <returns>The coordinates.</returns>
/// <param name="x">The x coordinate.</param>
/// <param name="y">The y coordinate.</param>
/// <param name="theta">Theta.</param>
/// <param name="ThetaInRad">If set to <c>true</c> theta in RAD.</param>
public Vector2 RotatedCoordinates(float x, float y, float theta, Vector2 center, bool ThetaInRad = false)
{
    if(!ThetaInRad)
        theta *= Mathf.Deg2Rad;

    Vector2 XY = new Vector2((Mathf.Cos(theta) * (x - center.x) - Mathf.Sin(theta) * (y - center.y)) + center.x, (Mathf.Sin(theta) * (x - center.x) + Mathf.Cos(theta) * (y - center.y)) + center.y);
    return XY;
}
```

}

Now attach this to your Camera (which should be a child of the empty GameObject) and remove the TouchCamera script. You'll notice two fields inside the CameraControl component, one that reads "Center Of Rotation" and one that reads "Camera". Drag the Empty GameObject and your Camera onto these fields respectively. This script will throw Null Reference Errors if you skip this step. Now just hit play. When you click the `Toggle For Rotation` button in the top left corner of the play window, you will be able to rotate the camera by dragging either the mouse pointer or a single finger around the center of the screen. You can unparent the Camera from the Empty GameObject and the script will still work. You can also orbit around any point in space by providing a different Transform. With a bit of editing, you could also eliminate the Transform entirely and use a Vector3 as the reference point in World Space, but you would need to control the Camera's actual rotation yourself without the line `transform.LookAt(CenterOfRotation);`. You can change the axis of rotation by editing three lines, located at roughly line 30, line 145, and line 151.

Comment: Wow! Seriously appreciate the help! Thanks :D